# Issue with the Connection String in Visual Studio Unit Test

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, connection-string

I am developing an MVC3 application in C#.

The application has several projects. Since I want to test the behavior of the Repository, the relevant projects are the **Repository project** itself and the **Unit Test project**.

I am facing an issue in testing phase, since everytime I run a test it launches an exception

**Test method UnitTest1.Repository_IsNotNull threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.**

I already encountered this exception other times and the only thing I had to do was copying the **ConnectionString** from the referenced project **web/app/.config** file (this case the Repository) to the referencing one (in this case the **UnitTest**).

The problem in this case is that **UnitTest** project does not have neither an app.config nor a web.config file.

What can be the cause of this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just add an app config file to the unit test project. Add -> New Item -> General -> Application Configuration File.

You don't mention which test framework you use, but this works fine with MSTest.

Comment: Sometimes I feel really dumb! It worked. I was watching the MVC Storefront video and he does perform the test on the Repository as I do, without adding the app.config. How comes? http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-2-the-repository-pattern